# Android returns empty string HTTP

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I have a problem. I have a class `AsyncTaskActivity` that has within it the method `downloadUrl` that communicates with a server php through `HttpURLConnection`. The server php, that communicates with MySql DB, should return, depending on the type of element, a string text or a string in json format. `HttpURLConnection` returns an empty string, when type of element returned by server is a string text. 
This is class `AsyncTaskActivity`.

```
public class AsyncTaskActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private Context context;
String serverParameters;
public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
String url = null;
private ProgressDialog pd;

public AsyncTask(Context c, String s, AsyncResponse<String> delegate) {
    this.serverParameters = s;
    this.context = c;
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {
        url = downloadUrl(strings[0]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return url;
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pd.setTitle("Please Wait...");
    pd.setMessage("Loading...");
    pd.show();
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    System.out.println("RESULT = " + result);
    delegate.processFinish(result);
    pd.dismiss();
}

private String downloadUrl(String targetURL) throws IOException {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        // Create connection
        url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        // Send request
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(serverParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        // Get Response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        String data = convertStreamToString(is);
        is.close();
        return data;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

This is class `AvailabilityActivity`. When I send a request to the server must be specified as parameters type element, access type(read, write, change, delete) and json to write. 
In this case, when I send a request to the server (type element = "expertise", access = "read", json to write = ""), I obtain an empty string. Type element "expertise" should return a string text. 
In `Riepilogo.setOnClickListener` `serverParameters` is initialized, `sendRequest()` execute `AsyncTaskActivity()`.

```
public class AvailabilityActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AsyncResponse<String> {
private Spinner spinner;
private Spinner spinner1;

/* Parameters Expertise*/

private static final String TIPO_ELEMENTO = "expertise";
private static final String ACCESSO = "read";
private AsyncTaskActivity send_request;
private String serverParameters;
private JSONObject jsonObject;
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
AvailabilityEntity availabilityEntity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_availability);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    Riepilogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            date_ = date.getText().toString();
            startTime_ = startTime.getText().toString();
            endTime_ = endTime.getText().toString();
            timeEditText_ = timeEditText.getText().toString();
            availabilityEntity = new AvailabilityEntity(date_, startTime_, endTime_, itemSpinner, timeEditText_);
            showSummary();
        }
    });

    serverParameters = generateParameters(TIPO_ELEMENTO, ACCESSO, "");
    sendRequest();
}

private String generateParameters(String tipoElementoLogin, String accesso, String s) {
    String parameters = "accesso:" + accesso + ", elemento:" + tipoElementoLogin + ", jsonDaScrivere:" + s;
    return parameters;
}

private void sendRequest() {
    send_request = new AsyncTaskActivityString(this, serverParameters, this);
    send_request.execute(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.serverQuery));
}

@Override
public void processFinish(String output) {
    System.out.println("Value: " + output);
    // Aggiunge lista expertise dal server in spinner
    list.add(output);
    ArrayAdapter<String> array_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    array_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(array_adapter);

}
```

Comment: Is the whole string empty or just the element? Are you able to get the JSON string through other methods like using a browser to test?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is server-side (PHP).

Comment: Which can be a possibile solution?

Comment: `class AsyncTaskActivity extends AsyncTask`. Not nice. Confusing. This has nothing to do with an Activity. Better call it MyAsyncTask or something like that.

Comment: If the php script sends a text or a json text then the server always sends a text. So always a text is received as you use the same code to receive it. Better blame the php script. All your activity code is much to much. Why do we have to see and read that all?

Comment: I reduced the code. Now you clearer?

Comment: In sendRequest () method, you are creating object of AsyncTaskActivityString. But the code you posted above has different name as AsyncTaskActivity. Are you using correct class?

Comment: sorry I was wrong to write post

Comment: First of all you can delete the post. If not then try to use any browser on your Android with url from php and see what is the real answer from the Android point of view.

Comment: I have only one post now.I have no ability to access the server php

Answer (score 0):

It Seems you forget to call connection.connect().
Try with this piece of code:

```
private String downloadUrl(String targetURL) throws IOException {
   ...
   ...

   // Get Response
   connection.connect();
   int http_code = connection.getResponseCode();

   String data = null;
   if (http_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
      data = this.convertStreamToString(connection.getInputStream());
   }
```